# execute script on git init

Tags: git, bash, templates, init, githooks

I would like to automate some tasks I made every time I use git init command.

I looked at the different templates but I don't even know if it's possible to execute a script directly after an init.

An idea ?

Comment: Out of curiosity, how frequently do you do that?

Comment: Every time I create a new repo. I want to create directly a .gitignore an commit it as my first commit

Comment: I was more wondering how frequenly you create new repositories for wanting this to be automated?

Comment: I'm in a testing phase so it's like 10 init in a day

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is not a hook for "on init" - especially given that hooks are per-repository, and when using `init` you're by definition setting up a new repository which wouldn't have any hooks yet.

What you could do instead is write a shell script which runs `git init` for you and then also runs your tasks. Then you'd just run that script instead of `git init`.

Comment: Yes I tagged hooks because it was such a comportment I was looking for. Well, let's go for a script. Thx !

Answer (score 2):

`.gitignore` is for version-controlled patterns. Another file that can include patterns to ignore is `$GIT_DIR/info/exclude`. This file is copied from the template used to create a new repository. By default, that is stored in something like `/usr/share/git-core/template`. You can specify your own template using the `--template` flag to `git init`. You would make a copy of the default template somewhere, such as `~/my-git-template`, then edit `~/my-git-template/info/exclude` to include the patterns you want in the initial repository. To create your new repository, run

```
git init --template ~/my-git-template
```

See `man gitignore` for the differences between `.gitignore` and the `exclude` file to see if this approach would work for you.